# AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'. Did you mean: 'TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'?

Tags: python

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import tweepy
import config
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import plotly.graph_objects as go

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
                           config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(config.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                      config.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Problem with my code, it is not running with the twitter key. The module has no attributes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `config` module that you are attempting to import and read off of is not what you want.

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY and TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET are not constants that you can get from a module. These are values that you must input yourself. There is perhaps a piece of code missing at the start of your application that looks like this:

```
config = {
    'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY': 'ENTER YOUR TWITTER CONSUMER KEY',
    'TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET': 'ENTER YOUR TWITTER CONSUMER SECRET'
}
```

Take a look at this [article](https://maxbridgland.medium.com/login-with-twitter-in-python-a-2020-guide-964b0fea9c6b) for more help. Goodluck!